# What's the ideal program to programming a Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I don't know if I'm using the right program to do a map in google.

I using Dreamweaver to programming my site.

I will use on it HTML for the page, with javacript, them i wanna do a save waypoint database with mysql and php.

I dont know if using Dreamweaver is the best way, what do you think ? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209126/good-javascript-ide-with-jquery-support) should answer your question.

I use Eclipse with the [Aptana](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) plugin for HTML, javascript, CSS and Python. I know you can also use it for PHP. It's pretty good.

Comment: Thanks guy, I will try Eclipse to see if I can resolve some problems that I can't in DreamWeaver =)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to display on your page. Considering the simplest case scenario, you can use simple html & javascript. Add jQuery if you need to parse JSON. If your waypoints (I am assuming this will be some static fully qualified address location) doesn't change often, then you will not need MySQL DB at all. I hope it helps.